# What does "Relates with understanding to manifestations of turbulent emotions in others" mean?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences

I'm trying to translate sociotypes' description, and I saw this sentence and couldn't understand clearly what does it mean.. 
this is as it came: "  CHARACTER: This individual is very interested in relations between people. Values understanding, tolerance, capacity for compromise for the sake of harmony in relations. Attempts to be helpful, responsive, and attentive towards everyone. Accepts people as they are; forgives their weaknesses and does not seek to change them by force. Tries to adhere to the principles of fairness and compassion. Predisposes others towards trust. Can patiently listen out his conversation partner. *Relates with understanding to manifestations of turbulent emotions in others*; tries to calm the person down, give some useful advice. If this does not help, knows how to wait patiently until the person calms down on his or her own. Does not need verbal confirmation of feelings himself - he understands everything without words. Stable and persistent in his sympathies and affections. Cherishes soulful harmony, his own and that of others. If his partner does not fully satisfy him, he departs without much commotion and sorting out the relationship."

Answer (score 1):

*Relates with understanding to manifestations of turbulent emotions in others* basically means this person is able to be sympathetic or understanding towards people who are overly emotional and, for example, cannot control their temper or get easily offended ("turbulent emotions").

To **relate to someone** means to identify with this person, to sympathize with them, to understand the way they feel.

> **relate to someone/something:** to be able to understand a situation or
>   the way that someone feels and thinks
>
> *Martin had always found it easier to relate to women.*
>
> *The programme deals with scientific subjects that ordinary people can
>   relate to.*

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/relate-to